# Client.guilds is not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot. When run `console.log(client.guilds)` from the ping.js it returns `undefined`.  But when I run `console.log(client.guilds)` from the index.js  it returns an array. My file structure looks like this:

- discord-bot/index.js
- discord-bot/commands/ping.js

File contents ping.js:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('ping')
                .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
        async execute(interaction) {
        client = require('./../index.js');
console.log(client.guilds);
        
        }
};
```

Comment: How do you export your client or do you at all export your client in index.js?

Comment: module.exports = {client};  When I run consile.log(client); from ping.js it doesn't return undefined

Comment: odd, forming an answer

Comment: Voted to close this one as a typo but chances are it's a duplicate. If you use `module.exports = {client}`, you're exporting an object with a `client` property so `client = require('./../index.js')` should be `const { client } = require('./../index.js')`. You could also just use `interaction.client` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't destructure the imported object.

```
const { client } = require('./../index.js');
```

Thanks Zsolt Meszaros.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that no guilds are cached in the export state ( you should either consider exporting your client after the ready event is triggered or fetch all guilds )

```js
client.guilds.fetch()
```

fetches all your guilds and caches them, you can incorporate the snippet in your code like so:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js'),
client = require('./../index.js');
module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('ping')
                .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
        async execute(interaction) {
        client.guilds.fetch().then( ( guilds ) => console.log(guilds))
        }
};
```

another friendly approach to a slash command handler usually is declaring `client` as a formal parameter in your `execute` function and call the function in your `interactionCreate` which is chained to your `index.js` file, further handling all the events by binding it directly to the `client` instead of exporting it like so:

`index.js`

```js
// file being the individual file ( you can loop through your events folder 
const event = require(`./events_dir/${file}`),
eventName = file.split(".")[0];
client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
```

`interactionCreate.js`

```js
// command representing the individual command from your commands collection
module.exports = (client, interaction) => {
command.execute(client, interaction);
}
```

`ping.js`

```js
execute(client, interaction) {
console.log(client.guilds);
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned that `client.guilds` is undefined so `client.guilds.fetch()` will throw a `TypeError` with an error `Cannot read properties of undefined`. I'm also not sure why you would use `await` first then `then()` on the same promise. The real problem is that OP is exporting an object (`{client}`) and forgot to destructure once it's imported. It means the imported `client` is an object with a `client` property (`{client}`). `console.log(client.client.guilds);` would also work for them.